# Android lollipop create a folder in USB OTG

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, usb-otg

Unable to create a folder in USB storage using this method:

```
File dest = new File("storage/usbotg/NewFolder");
dest.mkdirs();
```

the same method working fine in device storage

```
File dest = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/NewFolder");
dest.mkdirs();
```

but not in usb storage , any suggestion?

The device is Lenovo TAB2 A10-30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Solution](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-z2/help/write-sd-card-permissions-android-5-0-2-t3089933) for rooted devices only edit `plattform.xml` file in `/system/etc/permissions`

from

```
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_r" />
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
</permission>
```

to

```
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_r" />
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
    <group gid="media_rw" />
</permission>
```

Save the file then reboot , this is a solution for SDCard also.

Comment: What about unrooted devices?